# How to aligning Pill items and generally improve my code?

Tags: html, css

I'm building my own Pill component using HTML:

```css
.panel1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.panel2 {
  width: 100px;
}

.pill {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pill-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: black;
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: white;
}

.pill-text {
  flex: 1;
}

.pill-icon {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 18px;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel1">
  <div class="pill">
    <div class="pill-content">
      <div class="pill-text">
        Why is that text breaking as it fits in width?
      </div>
      <div class="pill-icon">
        X
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel2">
  <div class="pill">
    <div class="pill-content">
      <div class="pill-text">
        Test
      </div>
      <div class="pill-icon">
        X
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pill">
    <div class="pill-content">
      <div class="pill-text">
        Very big text that does not fit in width
      </div>
      <div class="pill-icon">
        X
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
```

My problems:

1. I need to position text always on the left side of the Pill.
2. I need to keep the close icon (I´m using an `X` here but that will be a font awesome icon) always vertically centered.
3. I can´t see why my text is breaking on `panel1`. I expected the text to break only when the panel size is smaller that text + icon.

Can I make that HTML/CSS simpler?

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/j7ka596e/6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some modifications to your code to give you the desired result:

```css
/* recommended */
.panel1 *,
.panel2 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.panel1 {
  /*width: 100%; by default*/
}

.panel2 {
  width: 100px;
}

.pill {
  display: inline-flex; /* modified, since you're using flexbox */
}

.pill-content {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-direction: row; by default*/
  font-size: 12px;
  /*vertical-align: middle; has no effect here*/
  align-items: center; /* now its vertically centered */
  /*padding: 0; already covered*/
  border: 1px solid blue; /* shorthand */
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.pill-text {
  /*flex: 1; not necessary, the culprit for breaking*/
}

.pill-icon {
  /*flex: 1; not necessary since you're using max-width*/
  max-width: 18px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-align: center; /* for horizontal alignment */
}
```

```html
<div class="panel1">
  <div class="pill">
    <div class="pill-content">
      <div class="pill-text">
        Why is that text breaking as it fits in width?
      </div>
      <div class="pill-icon">
        X
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel2">
  <div class="pill">
    <div class="pill-content">
      <div class="pill-text">
        Test
      </div>
      <div class="pill-icon">
        X
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="pill">
    <div class="pill-content">
      <div class="pill-text">
        Very big text that does not fit in width
      </div>
      <div class="pill-icon">
        X
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some simplification tips (as I cannot comment):

1. For all values that are 0, you can drop the units (px, etc.)
2. You can shorten your code by using the border shorthand: `border: 1px solid blue`. Luckily there's no need to specify each attribute individually
3. `background-color: white;` is specified twice for `.pill-content`, unless I'm missing something.